# Creating a simple yes/no dialog box in a view (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I've got an onCreateDialog method in my activity, which has a case switch to bring up different dialogs that I want to display depending on the request.

I cannot use the showDialog() method from my view because it's not accessible from the context that is passed when the view is created. At least, I can't find a way to access it.

How do I use showDialog from my application's view?  Do I need to create a listener? And if so, how? Is there a better method?

Here is my onCreateDialog code that exists in my application's activity:

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    AlertDialog alert=null;
    switch(id) {
    case DIALOG_GAMEOVER_ID:
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("You died. Play again?")
               .setCancelable(false)
               .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       //init();
                       //oGameState = eGameState.PLAYING; 
                      dialog.cancel();
                   }
               })
               .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       finish();
                   }
               });
            alert = builder.create();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    return alert;
}
```

I tried passing a reference to my activity, and I get crashes. Perhaps I am doing it wrong?

In my activity:

```
    // set our MainView as the View
    oNebulaMainView = new NebulaMainView(this, this);
    setContentView(oNebulaMainView);
```

In my view:

```
public NebulaMainView(Context context, Activity oActivity) {
    super(context);
    // adding the callback (this) to the surface holder to intercept events
    getHolder().addCallback(this);

    // create the game loop thread
    thread = new NebulaMainThread(getHolder(), this);

    setFocusable(true);

    oActivity.showDialog(DIALOG_GAMEOVER_ID);
}
```

Comment: Does NebulaMainView inherit from view? What does the exception log say the error is?

Answer (score 1):

I may be missing something here, but what is stopping you from just calling:

`alert.show()`

Just make the alert accessible to the view, and call that form inside your view.

Comment: I'm using the practice that google has outlined in the docs. if I were to alert.show(), I don't believe it's attached to the activity. Quote from the docs: "A dialog is always created and displayed as a part of an Activity. You should normally create dialogs from within your Activity's onCreateDialog(int) callback method." The onCreateDialog then gets called when you use showDialog(int).

Comment: Salx, showDialog() appears to be used when you are loading a dialog from a resource. The dialog in this case is created in a programmatic fashion. If you notice, you are passing the activity in to the alert dialog when you call AlertDialog.Builder(Context context);

Comment: Nowhere in the documentation does it mention that showDialog() is for loading from a resource.

Comment: Salx, my bad. I think I understand now. I guess you might try saving a reference to your activity when it starts for the purpose of letting views call showDialog() on it. I do believe that even if you use alert.show(), it is still attached to an activity. The tutorial you reference does seem cleaner though.

Comment: I do not think that will work, because this app is multithreaded. The oncreatedialog method in the activity needs to handle the creation of the dialog. or I have to find some way to handle this asynchronously, on the UI thread. (see my comment to kevin below.. similar)

Comment: So you can't pass a reference to your activity to the view, and have the view call showDialog()? I don't see how that would break a multi-threaded app. The activity would still be handling the dialog creation, but you have to somehow tell the activity to show the dialog, right?

Answer (score 0):

declare alert as an instance variable

Comment: Could you explain this in a little more detail? If I declare alert as an instance variable, how do I access that from a view? Yes, I could pass a reference to it when the view is created. However, these dialog boxes need to be created from this onCreateDialog method, and on the UI thread. this is a multithreaded app, and I don't think I can just pop up dialogs anywhere I want. The activity should handle it.